# "Only non-static member functions may be virtual"

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Getting error, but not understanding the behaviour:

```
class A {
    virtual void foo() = 0;
    virtual int bar();
}
```

Here I am getting error "only non-static member functions may be virtual"
I gave implementation for `bar();`.

Answer (score 3):

The error message is missleading, the problem is that `bar` has no return type, which is illegal.

Comment: SOrry for typo, return value is int

Comment: @Sijith So the code you have is `virtual int bar();`?

Comment: @Sijith a typo is `virutal` instead of `virtual`....

Comment: Yes David, its an interface class. All other function in my class is virtual

Comment: @Sijith post the code on ideone.com see if you get the error there.

Comment: @Sijith So from what you're telling me, there should be no problem. [See here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/9c94dcad25dcdf52847f58a9fced8cfc)

Comment: Thanks for helping me Luchian & david. My source code is little huge and diff from what I posted here. Let me checka nd revert U.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Static members are shared (statically) among all instances of the class as opposed to virtual functions which expose dynamic behavior and allow different execution according to the object type. So it makes no sense to have static virtual functions.

Besides that the code you presented has no static functions so please post the full version here.